# How to remove text on topbar in wordpress i-max theme(remove blue color)

Tags: html, wordpress, material-design

[image: please check the image the blue section i want to remove]

> Trying to change the HTML OF THE THEME but don't get any option for it in topbar with wp-admin is there any other way

Comment: The image and the information you provided is not enough to diagnose the issue. At least provide theme url or proper information to solve the issue.

Comment: imax is the theme is it possible to do it or not ? Inspect element I can find it but when I tried with ftp I don’t get the file in Wordpress? And from wpadmin it’s just provide to change the number

Comment: Yes that is possible, Try it with specific div for that and make css for it with display:none;

Comment: I don’t want to remove all I just want to remove call us text and keep WhatsApp

Comment: You don't have to remove "all" of it. What @Ravi said can be done. Since there's CSS that makes the area blue, means that there is a specified element which you can target within that area only, else there is no way that only "that" specific part turns blue, unless they used some very overcomplicated javascript to achieve that for absolutely no reason. Simply find that class/id/whatever and set it to hidden with CSS. Other than that, you'll need to construct a child theme and edit the HTML yourself.

Comment: Inspect and when that area is being highlighted click on + button from inspect element - console and and add css display:none; . I hope this will help you. :) Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about this.

1) Find the desired element and target it with CSS to set the property of the element to `hidden`. You can find the element by using the browser developer tools (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome), select the blue area, figure out the class, id or whatever selector it has.

2) Create a Child theme of the existing theme and edit the HTML code directly.
There should be more than enough information on Google on how to create a Child Theme. There are even "one click" Child Theme add-ons out there as far as I'm aware of.
The reason you'd want to do this in a Child Theme, is because if you do it on the original theme, the changes you make will be overwritten when the theme has an update.